# Java 8 Sorting based on 3rd value

Tags: sorting, java-8, comparator

This code sorts hashset values firstly by First Name and then by Last Name. If 2 persons have same first name and last name, i want to sort them by their ID values. Please help me to understand how to compare against 3rd value in this situation.

```
public static void multiple_sort(HashSet<Person> personSet) {

    Comparator<Person> byFirstName = (f1, f2) -> f1.getFirstName().compareTo(f2.getFirstName());

    Comparator<Person> byLastName = (f1, f2) -> f1.getLastName().compareTo(f2.getLastName());

    personSet.stream().sorted(byLastName.thenComparing(byFirstName)).forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already chained the comparators one time so this doesn't change if you want to compare by their ids, you chain them a third time:

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstName).thenComparing(Person::getLastName).thenComparingInt(Person::getId))
```

Note that I used method references here, this makes the code shorter and more readable.